# Ubuntu server boots, then shows blinking cursor

Tags: boot, server, lts

My Ubuntu server boots but then shows a blinking cursor. It passes GRUB and I get the boot log output and all seems fine, however I get no shell after booting. I can boot into recovery just fine however I am now unable to ssh in as my network configuration has changed.

Can anyone aid me in troubleshooting this issue? Thanks